# Disable Windows Forms Authentication on startup in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have a scenario where some of the developers on my team need to do development work but aren't joined to our domain. We are currently using Windows Authentication via Active Directory in our ASP MVC 5 application. What I want to do basically is say :

```
#if DEBUG

if (Enviroment.Domain == null)
{
   //Turn off authentication in web.config and allow any user.
}

#endif
```

Then in my RoleAuthorize attribute I will do a similar check and just return true if I detect they are a user outside the domain.

When we deploy the app to our client they will be using Windows Authentication as well but in a different domain. But I have a config setting I change for that to match their environment. But our goal is to test using AD to mimic there environment. I have searched all over google and haven't found a solution to meet my needs. All I can think of is using these events to intercept and turn authentication off  :

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered having authentication off (or allow all) in the web.config, and then use a config transform for your target deployment environments (QA, Prod, etc)?

Comment: That is what we are doing now. But some people still may want to do what I asked above for local dev if they have an offshore team.